# The system cannot find the file specified - WEB-INF config file running on Tomcat 6

Tags: java, web-applications, tomcat6

I have a web application deployed as a war in Tomcat 6. I am trying to read a config file under WEB-INF/ from a java class packaged in a jar under WEB-INF/lib. I get:

The system cannot find the file specified

Code:

```
Properties props = new Properties();
File propsFile = new File(".\config.properties");
InputStream stream = this.getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(propertiesFilePath);

if (stream != null){
   props.load(stream);
   log.debug("stream not null");
}

else
    props.load(new FileInputStream(propsFile));
```

It works fine in a server in production but in our test server it doesn't. Could it be server config related?

Comment: Have you tried it without the backslash?

Comment: Yes, same result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
URL resource = new URL(this.getClass().getResource("."), "config.properties");
InputStream stream = resource.openConnection().getInputStream();
```